# I have output generated while making an api call from python script . I need only particular items from that output

Tags: python, json

I need only the total numberoflamps and total lampon and total lampoff from these block of output .How can i achieve it .There is multple building id whic has all these info . But i need lampon ,off and total number of lamps cumulatively .

```
{
"lampSummaryStatus": [
   {
        "buildingId": "93CB2950-46D0-4231-B21C-C4691ACFCC1D",
        "totalNumberOfLamps": 9,
        "totalLampOn": 0,
        "totalLampOff": 0,
        "totalLampUnknown": 9,
        "totalLampConnected": 0,
        "totalLampDisconnected": 9,
        "totalLampWithALS": 0,
        "totalLampWithoutALS": 9,
        "totalPolicyNull": 0,
```

Comment: this output is not any data structure that is known ... I dont  think this is the actual API output that you recieved,  and if it is the writer of that API needs some tar and feathers

Comment: Its a json output I have included the main details . I need to calculate the percentage of lamps connected .For that I need total lamps and lamps connected

Comment: what you posted is not valid json ... please post an actual representation of the data

Comment: Above is actual json output

Comment: lampsconnected = lampsStatus['lampSummaryStatus']

        sum(lamps['totalNumberOfLamps'] for lamps in lampSummaryStatus)
        sum(lampsOn['totalLampOn'] for lampsOn in lampSummaryStatus)
        lamps = int(lamps)
        lampsOn = int(lampsOn)
        percentageConnected = lampsOn*100/lamps
        print(percentageConnected)